# My Image is completely black, it is not showing 50% black and 50% white

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
blk = np.zeros((400,400,3),np.uint16)
cv2.imshow("black",blk)
print blk[300,300]

blk[:,200:]=[255,255,255]
cv2.imshow("black",blk)
cc = np.copy(blk)
cv2.imshow("blackc",cc)
key = cv2.waitKey()
if key==27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am not getting output window with 50% black and 50% white color.The window is filled with only black color.

However, I am getting the numpy array with 50% as (0,0,0) and 50% as (255,255,255) when I check this with 6x6 numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the third line of your code to

```
blk = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), np.uint8)
```

Have a look at [THIS DOC](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)